# How to remove optionals and array symbols from my JSON response?

Tags: json, swift, option-type

I am using below HTTP Post call and I am getting response with unnecessary symbols, how  to remove those symbols also how to store those values with variables.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

> My output response:
>
> Optionals("{\"name\":\"juju",\"result\":\"win\"}")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using String(data:encoding:) will create an optional string. All you need is unwrap the optional using a `guard let` statement.

```
guard let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
print("responseString = \(responseString)")
```